# my error in the java file where I wanted find current location

Tags: android

I am new to android , I have been assigned to make some changes on a project which was previously made in **eclipse** and now we are using **android studio**.

I have searched a lot over internet but I am not getting the solution that where I have to change in the code.

my code below

```
`package com.attorneygeneral;`
```

public class GetLocation extends Activity implements LocationListener {

```
ImageView img_back,img_search;
EditText search_loc;
TextView txt_location,txt_longitude,txt_latitude;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
double lat,lng;
static LatLng currentLoc;
protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener locationListener;
protected Context context;
String provider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.get_location);
    img_back=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);
    img_search=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_search);
    search_loc=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_loc);
    txt_location=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_location);
    txt_latitude=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
    txt_longitude=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 900000, 100,
            GetLocation.this);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider
                + " has been selected.");
        onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Location not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try 
    {
        if(googleMap==null)
        {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();    
        }           
         /*Marker hardingLaw = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
         position(currentLoc).title("Location"));

         googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLoc, 15));

         googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);*/
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    search_loc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            search_loc.setFocusable(true);
        }
    });

    img_back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });

    img_search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(search_loc.getText().toString())) {

            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // txtLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    // txtLat.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + ", Longitude:"
    // + location.getLongitude());
    System.out.println("Latitude Location :" + location.getLongitude()
            + "::" + location.getLatitude());
    lat = location.getLatitude();
    lng = location.getLongitude();

    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        List<Address> address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        int maxLines = address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLines; i++) {
            String addressStr = address.get(0).getAddressLine(i);
            builder.append(addressStr);
            builder.append(" ");
        }

        String finalAddress = builder.toString(); // This is the complete
                                                    // address.
        System.out.println("address :" + finalAddress);

        txt_latitude.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        txt_longitude.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
        txt_location.setText(finalAddress); // This will display the final address.
        currentLoc = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        Marker hardingLaw = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
        position(currentLoc).title("Location"));
        //hardingLaw.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location_pin));

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLoc, 15));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);

    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
    } 
    catch (NullPointerException e) 
    {
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    System.out.println("Latitude disable");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    System.out.println("Latitude enable");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    System.out.println("Latitude status");
}
```

}`

Comment: increase min sdk version just

Comment: `minSdkVersion 9`

Comment: shared the image , kindly open second

Comment: changed the min sdk version to 9, not working...still same error
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Comment: Add this error in your question section .